# Disable automatig SVG tag from menu

Tags: menus, navigation, svg

I'm using twentyseventeen theme as base to design my own, but when i use wp_nav_menu to print menus, it adds some unwanted svg elements which break my design. Elements are like:

```
<svg class="icon icon-angle-down" aria-hidden="true" role="img"> 
<use href="#icon-angle-down" xlink:href="#icon-angle-down"></use> </svg>
```

How can i disable this?

Answer (score 2):

1. Copy `functions.php` from the parent theme into your child theme.
2. Edit `functions.php` to remove the offending SVGs.

NOTE: if wp_nav_menu() is called from another file (e.g., `header.php`), copy and edit that one instead.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `inc/icon-functions.php` file.

There is a code segment like this.

```
function twentyseventeen_dropdown_icon_to_menu_link( $title, $item, $args, $depth ) {
    if ( 'top' === $args->theme_location ) {
        foreach ( $item->classes as $value ) {
            if ( 'menu-item-has-children' === $value || 'page_item_has_children' === $value ) {
                $title = $title . twentyseventeen_get_svg( array( 'icon' => '' ) );
            }
        }
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_item_title', 'twentyseventeen_dropdown_icon_to_menu_link', 10, 4 );
```

Delete or comment this segment. This will remove svg dropdown icons from nav menu.